# Unable to add to cart configurable product with swatches Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-view, swatches

I have create the configurable product and assign attribute as swatches instead of drop-down. Swatches will display properly but unable to work for add to cart process like freeze when click on any swatch.

Comment: please check console log after add to cart

Comment: Unable to select swatch options. When i click on swatches option, it's not selected so unable to make add to cart product